# annotation proxy-body-size doesn't work in kubernete nginx-ingress

Tags: nginx, kubernetes

i have used item proxy-body-size as describe in document, and recreate my ingress.But it has no effect on the ingress-controller.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: fileupload-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: 100m
    nginx.org/rewrites: "serviceName=fileupload-service rewrite=/;"
```

and then i changed my configmap to change proxy-body-size.But it still doesn't work globally.

```
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: nginx-config
  namespace: nginx-ingress
data:
  proxy-body-size: "100m"
```

here's the document
https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/docs/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations.md#rewrite

what's wrong with my ingress..help!!!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xszq3.png)

Comment: why it works when i use "nginx.org/client-max-body-size: 100m" instead of "nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: 100m"

Comment: I can see from the annotations [page](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/docs/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations.md) that the key have to be quoted if it contains numeric value. Can you please try that and also restart your nginx pods? It would nice also to post your ingress describe output into the question instead of the image.

Comment: thanks. but i have tried to quote numeric value and it doesn't help

Comment: The different annotations `nginx.org` and `nginx.ingress` vary for two different `ingress-controllers`. See [this doc](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/blob/master/docs/nginx-ingress-controllers.md) for the differences. Can you check version your are using?

Comment: thanks so much!!!!!!!!!!!!  that's right!!! it solves my problem

Comment: If this was helpful would you consider accepting and [upvoting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote) the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different ingress controllers and the annotations for them vary.
So for `kubernetes/ingress-nginx` annotations starts with `nginx.ingress` and for
`nginxinc/kubernetes` the annotations starts with `nginx.org`.

Here is also a [good article](https://grigorkh.medium.com/there-are-two-nginx-ingress-controllers-for-k8s-what-44c7b548e678) showing more differences between them.

Comment: link is not working showing 404 error

Comment: @jayaprakashR added new link about ingress controllers